# Is ngOnInit() always called when navigating to a Page in Ionic 4 using navCtrl.navigateRoot()?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I cannot find official Ionic 4 Documentation on the new Ionic NavController and I am wondering whether or not we can assume that `ngOnInit()` will **always** be called on the Ionic Page component we are navigating to if we use `navCtrl.navigateRoot()` to trigger the navigation, even if an instance of that page already exists (which could be the case if we already visited that page).

It looks to me that at least when using `navCtrl.navigateRoot()`, the `ngOnInit()` method is always called on the page component we are navigating to. Still, I am not sure where I can find a confirmation on this behavior.

If that is not the case, what is the recommended way of making sure a method of a page component is executed every time the user navigates to the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic 3's navigation system was based on nav controller, while as you know Ionic 4 promotes Angular natural way to do navigation - router.

In Ionic 3 ngOnInit() would fire once for a component/page that gets into the nav stack.

So if we have a nav stack and navCtrl.navigateRoot() (or in ionic 3 it was navCtrl.setRoot()) is called **that will replace/remove old instance and will introduce new instance the lifecycle hook will get called**.

In Ionic 4 nav controller by design is expected to support same behavior, but it will not support lazy loaded components. So the reason you see ngOnInit firing each time you call nav.setRoot equivalent - is because you replace the component that was in the stack (effectively destroying it) and introducing a new component in its place.

In certain scenarios it won't get called (like if you start using push / pop and you will manage the stack ([page1,page2]) in a different manner that doesn't destroy your page/components - then the ngOnInit won't get called.

For life cycle hooks that are called each time component enters the view - as you recall it used to be ionViewDidEnter. Can you check if this one is still valid in ionic 4? Documentation is not saying it it not supported but also vice versa is not confirming it.

TBH when I would be switching to Ionic 4 I would think to leverage router based navigation as Nav Controller is more of a backwards compatibility feature in Ionic 4 now.

Comment: ionViewDidEnter should work (but it's unclear if that's just for backward compatibility) but right now it's broken as well, see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15260

Comment: confirmed its still working but not sure if its still the prefer method